# Cloning remote repository using Java Api

Tags: git, jgit

Is there any option to clone remote repository to local system using api, We need an api to checkout a particular version of source file from remote repository. Does Jgit having option to checkout source from remote repository or any other api having the option. kindly suggest an stable api that is capable for above requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The jGit library is used for the Git implementation of Eclipse. All requirements you mention above are supported by this tool.

Did you make a simple search on Google before asking? The first result pointed to the following thread: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/162717/
Hope it helps...

Answer (score 0):

JGit can do this by using the cloneRepository.